# Selecting everything of one cell value using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, vector-layer, select-by-expression

I'm trying to make a selection using PyQGIS.

The short snippet I'm working with is

```py
hej = iface.addVectorLayer('rs_map_Ale.shp', "", "ogr")
hej.selectByExpression("KOMMUNNAMN=ALE")
```

This works fine when selecting one row with a unique value, but `"ALE"` is in plenty of cells and I would like to select them all. I can't figure out how to write it. Tried a double = as well, didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `ALE` is a string, wrap it into single quotes.

```
" KOMMUNNAMN = 'ALE' "
```